# How to Convert an ActiveRecord::Relation by default

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I am working on a project that requires very specific methods to be called on an `ActiveRecord::Relation` object. These methods cannot extend `ActiveRecord::Relation` because the `Class` has it's own `initialize` method to determine if the object should be collected. I have tried a dozen ways to handle this but because of method chaining in `AR` I have been unable to accomplish this. Currently I have monkey patched `ActiveRecord::Relation` with a method that converts it like so:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Relation
    def to_claim_set
      exec_queries unless loaded?
      ClaimSet.new(@records)
    end
  end
end
```

Firstly I am sure this is an improper way to handle it. Secondly this causes me to have to call `#to_claim_set` constantly throughout the application.

I am hoping someone can assist on making this the default return after all method chaining is complete.

What I am hoping for is something like

```
Claim.policy_number('913006')
#=> ClaimSetObjectHere
```

But I need it to support chaining like `AR` does so that things like

```
Claim.policy_number('913006').by_program('Base')
#=> ClaimSetObjectHere
```

I also tried to patch the `#where` method inside `Claim` which works great unless I use a `scope` or I chain methods in which case it complains that `ClaimSet` does not define `default_scoped?`.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. As for *"Why would you want to do this"* like I said I am constantly calling this method throughout the application and I need the methods defined in `ClaimSet` for this to function properly.

**Note:** This is being used outside of `rails`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so what I ended up doing was imposing a wrapper for `ActiveRecord::Relation` like so:(removed specific business logic for brevity)

```
class ClaimSet
   def initialize(object)
     process_target(object)
    # ...
   end
  # ...
   def respond_to_missing?(method_name,include_private=false)
     @target.respond_to?(method_name)
   end
   def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
     if @target.respond_to?(method_name)
       ClaimSet.new(@target.send(method_name,*args,&block))
     else
       super
     end
   end
   private
     def process_target(object)
       @target = object if object.is_a?(ActiveRecord::Relation)
       @target = object.target if object.is_a?(ClaimSet)
     end
 end
```

Then in the `Claim` class.

```
 class Claim < ActiveRecord::Base
    class << self
      def where(*args)
        ClaimSet.new(super(*args))
      end
      def localized_scope(name,proc)
        scope_proc = lambda do |*args|
          ClaimSet.new(proc.call(*args))
        end
        singleton_class.send(:define_method,name,scope_proc)
      end
   end
 end
```

Then I define all my scopes as `localized_scope` e.g.

```
localized_scope :policy_number, ->(policy_number){where(policy_number: policy_number)}
```

Now it always returns a `ClaimSet` in place of an `ActiveRecord::Relation` for `#where` and `#localized_scope` and supports method chaining through `#method_missing`. It also removes the monkey patch on `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

If you have any other suggestions please let me know as I would be glad to entertain other ideas but this works for the time being.